# SABRE RevalidateItinRQ Cannot resolve Type

Tags: c#, .net, sabre

Working with SABRE RevalidateItinRQ i'm getting:

> Cannot resolve Type OriginDestinationInformationTypeOriginLocation to
>   a type definition for element OriginLocation.

```
<OTA_AirLowFareSearchRQ xmlns="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05" Target="Test" Version="4.1.0" ResponseType="OTA" ResponseVersion="4.1.0" SeparateMessages="true" TruncateMessages="false">
         <POS>
            <Source PseudoCityCode="xxxx">
               <RequestorID Type="1" Instance="1" ID="1">
                  <CompanyName Code="TN" />
               </RequestorID>
            </Source>
         </POS>
         <OriginDestinationInformation RPH="1">
            <ArrivalDateTime>2018-08-15T00:00:00</ArrivalDateTime>
            <OriginLocation LocationCode="KWI" />
            <DestinationLocation LocationCode="DXB" />
            <TPA_Extensions>
               <Flight Number="671" DepartureDateTime="2018-08-15T09:15:00" ArrivalDateTime="2018-08-15T12:10:00" Type="A">
                  <OriginLocation xsi:type="OriginDestinationInformationTypeOriginLocation" LocationCode="KWI" />
                  <DestinationLocation xsi:type="OriginDestinationInformationTypeDestinationLocation" LocationCode="DXB" />
                  <Airline Operating="KU" Marketing="KU" />
               </Flight>
            </TPA_Extensions>
         </OriginDestinationInformation>
         <TravelPreferences>
            <VendorPref Code="YY" PreferLevel="Unacceptable" />
            <CabinPref Cabin="Y" />
            <TPA_Extensions>
               <NumTripsWithRouting Number="10" />
               <TripType Value="OneWay" />
            </TPA_Extensions>
            <Baggage RequestType="C" Description="true" />
         </TravelPreferences>
         <TravelerInfoSummary>
            <SeatsRequested>1</SeatsRequested>
            <AirTravelerAvail>
               <PassengerTypeQuantity Code="ADT" Quantity="1" />
            </AirTravelerAvail>
            <PriceRequestInformation CurrencyCode="KWD" />
         </TravelerInfoSummary>
         <TPA_Extensions>
            <IntelliSellTransaction>
               <RequestType Name="50ITINS" />
            </IntelliSellTransaction>
         </TPA_Extensions>
      </OTA_AirLowFareSearchRQ>
```

Thanks for the help in advanced!

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: Looks like you're missing some XSD imports...

Comment: The problem is here: <OriginLocation xsi:type="OriginDestinationInformationTypeOriginLocation" LocationCode="KWI" /> Can you share how you are building this?

Comment: @Wisdoom Thank you. I have removed xsi:type="OriginDestinationInformationTypeOriginLocation"  from being serialized.